# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на узел в TreeView выводился текст?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я создаю электронный учебник. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на узел, а это к примеру "Математика", выводился текст. И какой компонент нужно добавить, чтобы к нему прилегал текст.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю начать с создания модели книги. Например, это может выглядеть так:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}
public class Section
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}
public class Chapter
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

У книги есть название и несколько частей. У каждой части название и несколько глав. У каждой главы название и содержимое. Добавьте по вкусу номера, картинки и что захотите.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SplitContainer splitContainer;
        TreeView treeView;
        Label labelContent;

        Book book;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            Size = new Size(800, 600);

            splitContainer = new SplitContainer { Parent=this, Dock=DockStyle.Fill };
            treeView = new TreeView { Parent=splitContainer.Panel1, Dock=DockStyle.Fill };
            labelContent = new Label { Parent=splitContainer.Panel2, Dock=DockStyle.Fill };

            FillTreeView();

            treeView.AfterSelect += TreeView_AfterSelect;
        }

        private void TreeView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            labelContent.Text = (string)e.Node.Tag;
        }

        void FillTreeView()
        {
            book = LoadBook();

            this.Text = book.Title;

            foreach (var section in book.Sections)
            {
                var sectionNode = treeView.Nodes.Add(section.Title);
                foreach (var chapter in section.Chapters)
                {
                    var chapterNode = sectionNode.Nodes.Add(chapter.Title);
                    chapterNode.Tag = chapter.Content;
                }
            }
        }

        Book LoadBook()
        {
            return new Book
            {
                Title = "Book Name",
                Sections = new List<Section>
                {
                    new Section
                    {
                        Title = "Section A",
                        Chapters = new List<Chapter>
                        {
                            new Chapter { Title="Chapter 1", Content=new string('a', 500) },
                            new Chapter { Title="Chapter 2", Content=new string('b', 500) }
                        }
                    },
                    new Section
                    {
                        Title = "Section B",
                        Chapters = new List<Chapter>
                        {
                            new Chapter { Title="Chapter 3", Content=new string('c', 500) },
                            new Chapter { Title="Chapter 4", Content=new string('d', 500) }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

В методе `LoadBook` должен быть код чтения книги из файла. Советую использовать сериализацию. Если незнакомы с ней, спросите отдельным вопросом.

В методе `FillTreeView` заполняем TreeView: в узлы помещаем названия частей и глав. Главное, на что нужно обратить внимание: в свойство `Tag` помещаем содержимое главы.

Подписываемся на событие `TreeView.AfterSelect`. Оно срабатывает при выборе узла мышкой или клавиатурой. В этом событии текст из свойства `Tag` помещаем в контрол, отображающий содержимое. Я использовал `Label`, но это может быть `TextBox`, `RichTextBox` или любой подходящий для ваших нужд контрол.

Answer (score 0):

```
class PageNode : TreeNode
{
   public string InsideText { get; set; }
}
```

Создаёте экземпляры PageNode, задаёте им свойство InsideText с текстом который вам нужно выводить, далее добавляете эти ноды в TreeView.
Далее при изменении при вызове события NodeMouseClick проверяете изменилась ли текущая выделенная нода, которая передаётся в параметре TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs, далее проверяете:

```
if (m is PageNode pn)
{
   MessageBox.Show(pn.InsideText);
}
```

Осталось только заменить вызов MessageBox.Show на вашу функцию, которая выведет тест в нужное вам место.