# Как запрограммировать компонент TreeView в C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, visual-studio-2022

Как запрограммировать TreeView так, чтобы при выборе определённого корня на компонент RichTextBox выводился определённый RTF-файл?

Comment: Нужно больше конкретики, отредактируйте вопрос, укажите, что именно не получается.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1276903/184217

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov выглядит как дубль, но я уже проголосовал